# How to get Base Path using RequestStackContext symfony class?

Tags: php, symfony

Reading this http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Asset/Context/RequestStackContext.html
I use

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Context\RequestStackContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

$con = new RequestStackContext(new RequestStack);
print($con->getBasePath());
```

But I get nothing nor error, just blank. what wrong I did?

EDIT:

Actually I want to pass it as third parameter to PathPackage, but it returns nothing. It should return getBasePath that is in RequestStackContext. How to fix it? my code is below:

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\PackageInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\PathPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\UrlPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\EmptyVersionStrategy;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Context\RequestStackContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;


$versionStrategy = new EmptyVersionStrategy();
$namedPackages = array(
    'img' => new PathPackage('images', $versionStrategy, new RequestStackContext(new RequestStack())),
);
$defaultPackage = new Package($versionStrategy);
$packages = new Packages($defaultPackage, $namedPackages);
$twig->addExtension(new AssetExtension($packages));
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Give an example please.

Comment: Please read "edit" part in my question.

Comment: What is this file? You are not using controllers?

Comment: No. It is not a controller.

Comment: Ok.. so what is it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please see "Edit2" in my post.

Comment: What is the purpose of this file? As I see it, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is blank because you create a new RequestStack instead of the one provided by Symfony, in a controller you should do for example:

```
public function indexAction(Request $r): Response
{
    print($r->getBasePath());
    die();
}
```

Comment: No. It is not a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

then:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
echo $request->server->get('CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT');
```

Symfony v5.1